# How to replace lines in a text file? C++

Tags: c++, string, replace, text-files

When using the replace line method I encounter the `std::out_of_range` exception I am not sure how to fix this. I know that the exception occurs when `pos > length()` but I am not sure how to modify my text file without this from happening. I am trying to replace `delLine` with `replaceLine` in the text file. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

```
unsigned int start;
start = 0;
unsigned int len;
unsigned int end;
std::string line;
std::ifstream fin;
fin.open("test.txt");
std::ofstream temp;
temp.open("temp.txt");
std::string delLine = "   color = vec4";
std::string replaceString = "   color = vec4("+red+", "+ green + ", " + blue +",1.0)";

while (getline(fin, line))
{
    start = start + line.length();
    len = replaceString.length();
    end = len + start;
    if (line.find(delLine)>start) {
        line.replace(start, end, replaceString);
    }
    temp << line << std::endl;
    line = "";
}

temp.close();
fin.close();
remove("test.txt");
rename("temp.txt", "test.txt");
```

Comment: The whole `start = start + line.length();` and `end = len + start;` seems suspect. Especially since `start` will begin by being out of bounds of the first line you read, and then you just continue to increase it.

Comment: @bruno I would accept an answer I am just very stuck and have been trying to get this to work for a while

Comment: @bruno sorry but I was new to stackoverflow and didn't use it often and didn't know how to accept answers, sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @bruno I have now corrected my error and accepted the answers if you have any advice on the problem I have with my code I would love to hear it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219397/discussion-between-daniel-gallo-and-bruno).

Comment: What do you think happens when you call [`line.replace(start, end, replaceString)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) when *both* `start` and `end` are out of bounds (which they *will* be)?

Comment: also do you want to replace `"something   color = vec4somethingelse"` by `"something   color = vec4("+red+", "+ green + ", " + blue +",1.0)somethingelse"` ? probably not, so do not check `line.find(delLine)` but `(line == delLine)`. Note also it is enough to add `"("+red+", "+ green + ", " + blue +",1.0)"` at the end of the line to get the expected result

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how do I make it so start and end are not out of bounds I don't understand

Comment: @DanielGallo bery simple, remove all concerning them, look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*getline* read **one** line (if possible) but your management of *start* and *end* is like if *line* receive the full content of the file, because of *start* and *end* management you try to access out of the string.

Out of that do you really want to replace `"something   color = vec4somethingelse"` by `"something   color = vec4("+red+", "+ green + ", " + blue +",1.0)somethingelse"` ? probably not, so do not check `line.find(delLine)` but `(line == delLine)`.

Note also it is enough to add `"("+red+", "+ green + ", " + blue +",1.0)"` at the end of the line to get the expected result because the beginning is unchanged.

So

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream fin("test.txt");
std::ofstream temp("temp.txt");

if (!fin)) {
  ...manage error...
}
else if (!temp) {
  ...manage error...
}
else {
  std::string lineToModify = "   color = vec4";
  std::string toBeAdded = "("+red+", "+ green + ", " + blue +",1.0)";

  while (getline(fin, line))
  {
    if (line == lineToModify)
      line += toBeAdded;
    temp << line << std::endl;
  }

  temp.close();
  fin.close();
  remove("test.txt"); /* you need to check success */
  rename("temp.txt", "test.txt"); /* you need to check success */
}
```

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string red = "RED";
  std::string green = "GREEN";
  std::string blue = "BLUE";
  
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream fin("test.txt");
  std::ofstream temp("temp.txt");
  
  if (!fin) {
    std::cerr << "cannot open test.txt" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (!temp) {
    std::cerr << "cannot open temp.txt" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  std::string lineToModify = "   color = vec4";
  std::string toBeAdded = "("+red+", "+ green + ", " + blue +",1.0)";
  
  while (getline(fin, line)) {
    if (line == lineToModify)
      line += toBeAdded;
    temp << line << std::endl;
  }
  
  temp.close();
  fin.close();
  
  if (remove("test.txt") != 0) {
    perror("cannot delete test.txt, result in temp.txt");
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (rename("temp.txt", "test.txt") != 0) {
    perror("cannot rename temp.txt to test.txt, result in temp.txt");
    return -1;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat test.txt 
something
   color = vec4
   color = vec44
    color = vec4
   color = vec4
end
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat test.txt 
something
   color = vec4(RED, GREEN, BLUE,1.0)
   color = vec44
    color = vec4
   color = vec4(RED, GREEN, BLUE,1.0)
end
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

I supposed the search line can be present several times, else if is possible to improve the code.

In case the search line can be not present in the input file better to use a boolean to know if at least a change was done, and if not to not delete/rename but delete the temporary file to not change the modification/creation date of the input file

Comment: @DanielGallo I corrected errors in my answer and put a full example with execution